# QueryObject for Rails - how to encapsulate set of operations on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I encapsulate a set of operations (most of which are essentially .where(...)) and apply it to different models, in a way that some of the models may not implement some of the operations and should return empty collections. (non-essential code skipped)

What I have designed (but not satisfied with):

```
class ActivityFinder

  def self.find(query, limit = nil)
    activities = get_activities(query)
    activities = activities.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse // some-kind of merge-sort
    activities = activities.slice(0, limit) if limit.present?
    activities
  end

  private

  def self.get_activities(query)
    activities = []
    activities += query.apply(ModelA)
    activities += query.apply(ModelB)
    activities += query.apply(ModelC)
    activities
  end
end

class ActivityQuery

  def created_before(time)
    @created_before = time
    self
  end

  def created_after(time)
    @created_after = time
    self
  end

  def apply(activity)
    activity = activity.where("#{activity.table_name}.created_at < ?", @created_before) if @created_before.present?
    activity = activity.where("#{activity.table_name}.created_at >= ?", @created_after) if @created_after.present?
    // more operations, not all of them are suported by ModelC
  rescue NoMethodError
    return []
  end
end
```

Usage

```
query = ActivityQuery.new.created_before(last_time).with_hash(...)
activities = ActivityFinder.find(query)
```

What I don't like:

- the rescue for NoMethodError
- if different models has different name for the field, it has to be handled as a `case` statement in the query, coupling in this way the query object with each of the models

So I'm searching for suggestions for better implementation

**UPDATE**

The problem is I want to pass any object that I got from an ActiveModel, e.g. ActiveRecord::Relation, so I can't just define a module with the methods (and override when needed) and include it in the models I'm using. The question is more to point in the right direction for a clean design, and not about implementation details, which I'll figure out somehow

Comment: instead of rescuing NoMethodError, you could just do something like: def method_missing(ignored_method_name, *args); return []; end

Comment: Override the method_missing of an ActiveRecord's subclass?

Comment: Well, if you can't put the model specific code into the model (where it belongs), you'll end up with a tightly coupled class.

Comment: Darhazer, no, in the sample code the NoMethodError was being rescued in a plain class, not an ActiveRecord subclass. Regardless, I upvoded Stefan's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original idea was to create some proxy object and defer method execution until the actual apply. I did it with more traditional approach, where each operation creates a criterion object (in my case it's called QueryOperation) and it's applied at later stage. The same functional issues still exists, but the code is much cleaner

```
class ActivityQuery

  def initialize
    @operations = []
    @operations.push(QueryOperationOrderBy.new('created_at', 'DESC'))
  end

  def for_user(user)
    @user = user
    self
  end

  def with_hash(hash)
    @operations.push(QueryOperationFindByHash.new(hash)) unless hash.blank?
    self
  end

  def limit(limit)
    @operations.push(QueryOperationLimit.new(limit))
    self
  end

  def created_before(time)
    @operations.push(QueryOperationLessThan.new('created_at', time))
    self
  end

  def created_after(time)
    @operations.push(QueryOperationGreaterThan.new('created_at', time))
    self
  end

  def apply(activity)
    @operations.each do |operation|
      activity = operation.apply(activity)
    end

    activity
  rescue NoMethodError
    return []
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid tight coupling, put the model specific code into the model:

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :created_before, ->(timestamp) { where("created_at < ?", timestamp) }
  scope :created_after, ->(timestamp) { where("created_at >= ?", timestamp) }
  scope :with_hash, ->(hash) { ... }
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :created_before, ->(timestamp) { where("other_column < ?", timestamp) }
  scope :created_after, ->(timestamp) { where("other_column >= ?", timestamp) }
  scope :with_hash, where('false') # empty, chain-able collection
end
```

Now you have a consistent interface you can program against:

```
class ActivityQuery

  def apply(activity)
    activity = activity.scoped
    activity = activity.created_before(@created_before) if @created_before.present?
    activity = activity.created_after(@created_after) if @created_after.present?
    activity = activity.with_hash(@hash) if @hash.present?
    activity
  end

end
```

No need to rescue `NoMethodError` and no more fiddling with the model's implementation details.

Comment: This means that I have to provide a with_hash method to each object that actually does not support hash. I would like to create a mixin that provides default implementations to all of those methods. But it does not work when I pass ModelA.includes(:some_relation) to the query object

Comment: Or you could just check if `activity.responds_to?(:with_hash)`

Comment: does not work, because rails provides `method_missing` method

Comment: There must be another reason, `respond_to?` doesn't invoke `method_missing`.

Comment: There's a typo in my first comment, it's `respond_to?` (without s). `responds_to?` (with s) is undefined and therefore handled by `method_missing`.

Comment: the problem with this approach is that I have to define all of the custom scopes to all of the models, no matter if they support the scope or not. And for some reason respond_to? gives me wrong information

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveRecord::Base#column_names

```
class Goodstuff < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_x_greater_than_y(x,y)
    if (scope_attributes + column_names).inlcude?(x)
      where('x > y')
    else
      []
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: as far as I know, try() will send message to the object, unless the object is nil, and will result in NoMethodError if the object exists but does not have .where method?

Comment: Oh, you are correct. So let me edit and give you the last option only.

Comment: @Darhazer also was missing an `include?` call afterwards the column_names.

Comment: it's not just the column names, I may use custom scope or other finder methods...

Comment: for scope you can use `valid_scope_name?`. What is the problem with the finder methods? Isn't enough to use an scope or attribute on it?

Comment: the valid_scope_name? is protected :) Yes, I know I can use `send` to use it externally

Comment: You are right, but `scope_attributes` is not... editing the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encapsulate your query objects, I have written a micro library that makes it really simple to move complex query logic outside of your models and controllers.

https://github.com/ElMassimo/queryable

It takes care of making your scopes chainable, and delegating methods like each and map to the actual query.

You could create a base object where you define the available operations (or rescue the `NoMethodError`), and then extend the query object if you need to modify or change any of the scopes.

```
ActivityFinder.find { |activities|
  activities.created_before(last_time).with_hash(...)
}

class ActivityQuery
  include Queryable::ActiveRecord

  # You can define the scopes as simple methods, which you can override in
  # subclasses.
  def created_before(time)
    where("created_at < ?", time)
  end

  # Rails-style scope syntax is also available
  scope(:created_after) { |time| where("created_at >= ?", time) }

  # You can add more methods to the query interface that just return self,
  # or none and then implement them in the more specific query subclasses.
  def with_hash(*args, &block)
    none
  end
end

class ModelAQuery < ActivityQuery
  # You can specify the collection that the query object works with by default.
  queryable ModelA

  # You can override a method defined in the superclass, since the scopes are
  # plain methods you could also share them with mixins.
  def created_before(time)
    where("measured_at < ?", time)
  end

  def with_hash(hash)
    where("timestamp = ?", hash[:timestamp])
  end

  # ...
end

# To solve that particular case you could pass a block to the find method
# and build the query.
class ActivityFinder
  ACTIVITIES = [ModelAQuery, ModelBQuery, ...]

  def self.find(limit=nil, &block)
    activities = get_activities(&block)
    # ...
  end

  def self.get_activities
    ACTIVITIES.map { |query_class| yield query_class.new }.flatten
  end
end
```